# Does each element in domain need result for onto functions?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

For onto functions, do all the elements in the domain have to give a result from the range? I know that for one-to-one, every single $x$ must give a result, and one that is a unique $y$. For onto functions though, does every $x$ in the domain have to give a result, as long as each $y$ appears at least once? If someone could help clear this up, it'd be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

For *any* function, each element of the domain gives a result. That is the definition of the domain: the domain are all elements $x$ for which $f(x)$ is defined.